# Combine SQL Query using two tables

Tags: mysql, sql

Is it possible to combine the queries into one call? The `UPDATE wp_term_taxonomy` one has to run after the first UPDATE wp_posts.

Here is the query, I'm just starting out on making queries:

```
UPDATE  `wp_posts` p 
    LEFT OUTER JOIN wp_term_relationships r ON r.object_id = p.ID
    LEFT OUTER JOIN wp_term_taxonomy x ON x.term_taxonomy_id = r.term_taxonomy_id
    LEFT OUTER JOIN wp_terms t ON t.term_id = x.term_id
    SET  p.post_type =  'recipe'
    WHERE p.post_type = 'post'
    AND t.slug = 'recipes' 
    OR t.slug = 'cocktails' 
    OR t.slug = 'breakfast' 
    OR t.slug = 'cookies-recipes' 
    OR t.slug = 'desserts'
    OR t.slug = 'main-course'
    OR t.slug = 'sides'
    OR t.slug = 'soups'
    OR t.slug = 'starters'

UPDATE wp_term_taxonomy SET taxonomy = 'recipe-categories' WHERE term_taxonomy_id IN (53,57,72,75,125,138,177);
```

Comment: Provide sample data, desired results, and an explanation of the logic you want to implement.

Comment: All the data works, where the top looks for categories and transfers them to a custom post type, while the bottom updates the taxonomies for the transferred posts. I just wanted to see if I can call it within one query, instead of calling it twice. Now I have to call the top query, then the bottom or it doesn't work.

Comment: Are you sure `UPDATE` does what you want? Using `AND` with `OR` without parentheses may not bode well?

Comment: or consider using `IN` - `AND t.slug IN ('recipes','cocktails','breakfast','cookies-recipes','desserts','main-course','sides','soups','starters') [MySQL IN](https://www.mysqltutorial.org/sql-in.aspx)

Comment: Why worry about it?

Comment: Also, a LEFT JOIN on an UPDATE is a really bizarre thing

Answer (score -1):

Consider using a `CASE` or `IF` expression for `SET` assignment. Below also adjusts `WHERE` logic to what you seemingly intended to do:

```
UPDATE `wp_posts` p 
LEFT OUTER JOIN wp_term_relationships r 
   ON r.object_id = p.ID 
LEFT OUTER JOIN wp_term_taxonomy x 
   ON x.term_taxonomy_id = r.term_taxonomy_id 
LEFT OUTER JOIN wp_terms t 
   ON t.term_id = x.term_id 
SET p.post_type = 'recipe',
    x.taxonomy = CASE 
                      WHEN x.term_taxonomy_id IN (53,57,72,75,125,138,177)
                      THEN 'recipe-categories'
                      ELSE x.taxonomy
                 END
WHERE p.post_type = 'post' 
  AND (   t.slug = 'recipes' 
       OR t.slug = 'cocktails' 
       OR t.slug = 'breakfast' 
       OR t.slug = 'cookies-recipes' 
       OR t.slug = 'desserts' 
       OR t.slug = 'main-course' 
       OR t.slug = 'sides' 
       OR t.slug = 'soups'
       OR t.slug = 'starters')
```

Comment: Unfortunately, I think that will update only those that have a relation with previous tables.

Comment: Indeed @FabienTheSolution, I should have mentioned the `x.taxonomy` will only adjust joined records. But OP's comment is confusing: *while the bottom updates the taxonomies for the transferred posts*. In actuality, second query updates all taxonomies by filtered IDs. Hopefully, OP can chime in if this works. Otherwise will be deleted.